# Add generic types to Promise.props(...) with Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I would like to create a typed Promise.props(...) utility function which returns the correct types according to the input object.

```
static async props<T extends {[key: string]: Promise<S>|S}, S, U extends { [key in keyof T]: S}>(obj: T): Promise<U> {
    const promises = [];
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[i];
        promises.push(obj[key]);
    }
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);

    return results.reduce((map, current, index) => {
        map[keys[index]] = current;
        return map;
    }, {});
}
```

So far what I've got is the type `T` which is the input parameter. I also defined `U` which has the same keys but should have different value types.

Is it possible to get the result type from a Promise and the same way I can get the keys of an input parameter.

Using the function should then look something like this:

```
const result = await this.props({
    val1: Promise.resolve('test'),
    val2: Promise.resolve(123),
    val3: ['a', 'b', 'c']
});
```

The IDE should then know that:

```
result.val1 is a string
result.val2 is a number
result.val3 is an array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
static async props<T>(obj: {[K in keyof T]: Promise<T[K]> | T[K]}): Promise<T> {
  // (I didn't look at the implementation)
}
```

Comment: I had to change ```obj[key]``` to ```obj[key as any]``` to make the compiler happy. Apart from that, it's working